# Minimal RAM requirement for raspbian os

Tags: raspbian

We are evaluating a scenario where we want to run raspbian os on minimal possible memory. I am fine with custom building it. Can someone throw some light on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without a GUI running, it should be okay with ~50 MiB.  It will start up at around 25 MiB however, so that doesn't leave you with much.

```
> free
             total       used       free 
Mem:        448376     401792      46584 
-/+ buffers/cache:      55896     392480
                        ^^^^^
```

That's a B+ running pidora, but raspbian is the same.  It's been on four or five days.  The largest userland process is actually `dhclient`, which manages DHCP for internet service, then `rsyslogd` (which is optional on pidora, but required on raspbian sans systemd), then `sshd`, then `systemd` (on raspbian, that would be `init`).  The init setup is reduced from stock (e.g., I don't use NetworkManager), but not drastically.

`free` and other tools don't report the memory used by the kernel, which is probably about 5-10 MiB.

You will get much better performance if you do leave a decent amount of free memory due to [file caching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_(computing)).

You can of course also use a [swapfile](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-add-a-swap-file-howto/) (raspbian does by default), but using significant disk swap will slow the system down.